# How to ignore some differences in diff command?

Tags: linux, bash, diff, vimdiff

`diff` has an option `-I regexp`, which ignores changes that just insert or delete lines that match the given regexp. I need an analogue of this for the case, when changes are between two lines (rather then insert or delete lines).

For instance, I want to ignore all differences like between `"abXd"` and `"abYd"`, for given `X` and `Y`.

It seems `diff` has not such kind of ability. Is there any suitable alternative for `diff`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could filter the two files through `sed` to eliminate the lines you don't care about. The general pattern is `/regex1/,/regex2/ d` to delete anything between lines matching two regexes. For example:

```
diff <(sed '/abXd/,/abYd/d' file1) <(sed '/abXd/,/abYd/d' file2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `sed '/regex/d' file` deletes all lines in `file` where a matching of `regex` occurs. Is there a way to delete not the line but only the matching part of it?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do. Can you edit your question with an example of two files you want to diff and what you want the result to be?

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work with recursive (`-r`) diff for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 31):

Improving upon the [earlier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4434370/581112) by John Kugelman:

```
diff <(sed 's/ab[XY]d/abd/g' file1) <(sed 's/ab[XY]d/abd/g' file2)
```

is probably what you may be looking for! This version normalizes the specific change on each line without deleting the line itself. This allows diff to show any *other* differences that remain on the line.

Answer (score 3):

You could use sed to replace instances of the pattern with a standard string:

```
diff <(sed 's/ab[XY]d/ab__REPLACED__d/g' file1) <(sed 's/ab[XY]d/ab__REPLACED__d/g' file2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming X and Y are single characters, then `-I 'ab[XY]d'` works fine for me.

Comment: This entirely ignores the line. If there are other differences in the line that you do care about, this will hide them.

Answer (score 2):

My open-source Linux tool 'dif' compares files while ignoring various differences.

It has many options for doing search/replace, ignoring whitespace, comments, or timestamps, sorting the input files, ignoring certain lines, etc.

After preprocessing the input files, it runs the Linux tools meld, gvimdiff, tkdiff, diff, or kompare on these intermediate files.

Installation is not required, just download and run the 'dif' executable from https://github.com/koknat/dif

For your use case, try the search and replace option:

```
./dif file1 file2 -search 'ab[XY]d' -replace 'abd' -diff
```